# Ionic 2: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: json, angular, http, ionic2

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase in my service class using:

```
return this.http.get('https://myfirstfirebaseproject-6da6c.firebaseio.com/products.json')
    .map(res => res.json());
```

In home.ts, I then subscribe to it using:

```
        this.productService.fetchProducts()
            .subscribe(data => {
              console.log(data)
              this.products = data;
            });
```

I output to home.html using:

```
<ion-card ion-item *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index" (click)="onItemClick(product)">
    <ion-card-header>
      {{ product.date | date }}
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-title>
        {{ product.title }}
      </ion-card-title>
      <p>
        {{ product.content }}
      </p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

but i keep getting the error

Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

I tried looking at similar issues but to no avail. Please help.

Comment: More than likely, what you are getting in the `data` from the API call is not an array, but an object. Use `console.log(data)` to see what it looks like, then make any changes you need to make.

Comment: Hi Richard, I get an object. Should I manually convert the object to array on my own?

Comment: Is there an array in the object somewhere? If there is, use it. If there is not, convert it somehow, or don't iterate in the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your JSON. https://myfirstfirebaseproject-6da6c.firebaseio.com/products.json
It returns an Object not an Array. That is why you cannot use returned data in ngFor.

```
{
    -KiTWPuI_TYt0b_Qi03Y: {
    amount: 0,
    category: "Baby",
    content: "I love cricket",
    date: "2017-03-01",
    title: "Cricket"
    },
    -Kid7fghtlxkyrOChQPk: {
    amount: "111",
    category: "Book",
    content: "updated content",
    date: "2017-04-01",
    title: "Cycling"
    },
    d9e7545c-90a3-4a57-97ab-ea3bf9171023: {
    amount: "12",
    category: "Baby",
    content: "COnten1",
    date: "2017-01-01",
    title: "Title2"
    }
}
```

Try this:

```
<ion-card ion-item *ngFor="let key of keys; let i = index" (click)="onItemClick(key)">
    <ion-card-header>
      {{ products[key].date | date }}
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-title>
        {{ products[key].title }}
      </ion-card-title>
      <p>
        {{ products[key].content }}
      </p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

In your component.ts:

```
keys: string[];
...
this.productService.fetchProducts()
            .subscribe(data => {
              console.log(data)
              this.products = data;
              this.keys = Object.keys(this.products);
            });
```

And modify your onItemClick() accordingly.

Comment: Wannadream, I am having some trouble with "let key of products.keys()" as keys is a undefined property.

Comment: I am surprised that it does not work. I make an example. Give me a second.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong usage. It should be Object.keys(products).

Comment: If direct expression cannot work in ngFor, you need to consume it into another property in component class. I will post an example.